# Query pulling all taxonomies, not one I am specifying

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to grab one random post from a custom Post Type I have that has a taxonomy that I give to it. For some reason it is pulling any post, no matter the category.

Here is my Post Type

```
if (!function_exists('register_recipe_post_type')):

//Registering Post Type

function register_recipe_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => __('Recipes'),
        'singular_name'       => __('Recipe'),
        'menu_name'           => __('Recipes'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __('Parent Recipe:'),
        'all_items'           => __('All Recipes'),
        'view_item'           => __('View Recipe'),
        'add_new_item'        => __('Add New Recipe'),
        'add_new'             => __('Add New Recipe'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Edit Recipe'),
        'update_item'         => __('Update Recipe'),
        'search_items'        => __('Search Recipes'),
        'not_found'           => __('No Recipes found.'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No Recipes found in trash.')
    );

    $rewrite = array(
        'slug'                => 'recipe',
        'with_front'          => false,
        'pages'               => true,
        'feeds'               => true,
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __('Recipe'),
        'description'         => __('Recipes'),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'taxonomies'          => array('vodka_type'),
        'supports'            => array('title','editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-palmtree',
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
        'capability_type'     => 'post'
    );

   register_post_type('recipe', $args);

   flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'register_recipe_post_type');

endif;
```

Here is my custom taxonomy

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function vodka_type_taxonomy() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Vodka Types', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Vodka Type', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Vodka Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Item:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Vodka Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Vodka Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Vodka Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Item', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate items with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Vodka Type', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Items', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Vodka Types', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'No items', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Items list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Items list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'vodka_type', array( 'post' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'vodka_type_taxonomy', 0 );
```

Here is the query I am executing that is pulling any taxonomy, not the one that I specify

```
// WP_Query arguments
$args = array (
'post_type'              => array( 'recipe' ),
'post_status'            => array( 'publish' ),
'orderby'                => 'rand',
'posts_per_page'         => '1',
'tax_query'              => array(
    'taxonomy' => 'vodka_type',
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => 'origin', // <-- This is the tax. it's supposed to be
),
);
// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if($query->have_posts()) :
  while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
   // Do Stuff With The Post
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

Comment: `tax_query` is an array of an array, not just an array. And you are talking about terms, not taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The solution was to include the tax query array inside another array:

```
// tax_query needs to be an Array of an Array
'tax_query'  => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'vodka_type',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => $type,
    ),
),
```